# vb .net excel index from column name

Tags: excel, vb.net

When G is passed to below code it returns 1 instead of 7.  Can anyone point me in the right direction please?  I'm trying to get the Excel column index from the column letter.  Thank you

```
Public Function ColLetterToColIndex(colLetter As String) As Integer
colLetter = colLetter.ToUpper()
Dim sum As Integer = 0

For i As Integer = 0 To colLetter.Length - 1
    sum *= 26
    Dim charA As Integer = Char.GetNumericValue("A")
    Dim charColLetter As Integer = Char.GetNumericValue(colLetter(i))
    sum += (charColLetter - charA) + 1
Next
Return sum
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (instead of GetNumericValue):

```
Dim charA As Integer = Asc("A")
Dim charColLetter As Integer = Asc(colLetter)
```

Everything else can stay the same.